# Raspberry pi 3 touch screen 3.5" not working fine but it does with 7"

Tags: pi-3, pi-2, touchscreen

I'm working with a pi 3, I use Jessica img and waveshare driver :

```
http://www.waveshare.com/wiki/3.5inch_RPi_LCD_(A).
```

I followed the instructions and the touchscreen 3.5" is working except for touch feature. I tried with other driver like adafruit https://cdn-learn.adafruit.com/downloads/pdf/adafruit-pitft-3-dot-5-touch-screen-for-raspberry-pi.pdf
or `https://www.elecrow.com/35-inch-480x320-tft-display-with-touch-screen-for-raspberry-pi-p-1385.html` but none of them allow the touch feature to be enable.

I was wondering if it was the pi which had a hardware problem since the touch screen was doing perfectely with a pi 2 : display GUI and touch responsive.

In my last attempt I connect the pi with an 7" offical touchscreen `https://www.kubii.fr/ecrans-pitft-raspberry-pi/1131-ecran-tactile-officiel-7-800x480-640522710829.html` and it was good.

So now I'm left stupefy and I hav no idea why it's working and not with 3.5 screen. I woul like to heard your thought on my problems thanks.

Hope we can find the reason :)

ps: I have not enought point to put more than 2 link... (T_T)

Comment: Hie, I'm not sure if there is an official display in 3.5" format but I saw many touchscreen 3.5" in the market.

Answer (score 1):

i cannot say if is generic or not that screen, but usually, you have to change the driver, mabe u PI3 has the driver for 7" enabled and not for 3.5" screen, 
I have several generic screens, so when I want to use 7" screen I put the command ./LCD-7... and I have to change the screen, but if I want to use 3.5" screen I have to put ./LCD-35..., also if you want to use some screen but u have HDMI connected it will take HDMI screen by default, u have to change that in config file

Comment: Thanks you for your response, I already tried the driver using ./LCD35-show, it allow to display the GUI on the touchscreen but it won't respond to any touch event with my finger/pen/object.

Comment: it depends on screen model but , if is connecteb via pins, some pins of that handle touch interaction, be sure they are well connected